# create a slider using your mouse with jquery from scratch

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to create a slider similar to:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Basically the idea is something very similar to the basic slider in the demo, except that in the handle that you grab with the mouse to slide will be numbers that change when you get to certain points. I think I can figure out the numbers part, but I'm completely stuck on how to start.

I want to do it from scratch with jquery... so no plugins. If anyone knows of any tutorials, or somewhere I could start that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depends. If you want to do it for the knowledge, I'd recommend having a look at the [jQuery UI source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js) ;)

If you want to do it because jQuery UI is too "heavy" then FYI, you can [customise which parts of it you download/use.](http://jqueryui.com/download)

### EDIT

Try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop

Comment: I still don't want to use a plugin, so option 2 is out. I do want the knowledge, but there is a lot of code that is not needed for option 1. I think if I figure out the drag and drop I could get most of it... didn't know if there were any tutorials that aren't using plugins of any kind

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have, and it works.

```
//sets the current position and offset variables
    var currentPosition;
    var offset;
    var rightOffset

    //looks for the mousedown event on the slider
    $("#slider").mousedown(function(e){
        //sets the offset = to the mouse coordinate of the page - the offset of the slider
        offset = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        console.log("offset: " + offset);
        $(document).bind('mousemove', mmHandler);
    }); 

    var mmHandler = function (e) {

            currentPosition = e.pageX - offset;

            //takes the mouse current position (minues the offset) and sets an absolute position
            $('#slider').css('left', currentPosition + "px");
            console.log("CURRENT POSITION: " + currentPosition);

            //checks to make sure it's within the box
            if(currentPosition <= 0){
                $('#slider').css('left', 0 + "px");
            }else if(currentPosition >= 380){
                $('#slider').css('left', 400-20 + "px");    
            }

            $("#slider").text($("#slider").css('left'));

        };


    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
      $(document).unbind('mousemove', mmHandler);
    });
```